# sles/opensuse os installation log

Tags: logging, installation, opensuse, sles

Is it possible to keep installation log off all events, tasks, say running commands, etc.. while installing SLES/openSUSE (or maybe another linux)?

It's not a problem lookup info in already running system, but it will be useful to have entire os installation log in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is definitely possible.  If the installation was performed using AutoYaST you should be able to set [reporting options](https://doc.opensuse.org/projects/autoyast/configuration.html#CreateProfile.Reporting) in the config file so the output will be logged.